# MEF: load a plugin from a different plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, mef

Is it possible to load a plugin from a another different plugin

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking... can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can as long as you're not creating a circular reference.  For instance, it's common to export a Logging Service in one "plugin", and consume it in many others.

Also, if your main application has an extension point (e.g. Drivers), one of the Driver plugins can itself have an extension point (e.g. Protocols) and someone else can write a plugin for that extension point.

[SoapBox Core](http://soapboxcore.com/) works like this.